# Loading Json properties in a popup using leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a geojson file (tide_gauges.geojson)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUMERO": "10569", "MAREGRAFO": "COCALZINHO", "FICHA": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4, -1 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUMERO": "50240", "MAREGRAFO": "PONTA DE PARANAPUA", "FICHA": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4, -2 ] } }...
```

I retrieved this Json file in a variable:

```
var estacoes = new L.geoJson();
estacoes.addTo(map);

$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "geojson/tide_gauges.geojson",
success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
        estacoes.addData(data);
    });
}
}).error(function() {});
```

I am in need to set all the feature properties (`NUMERO`,`MAREGRAFO`,`FICHA`,`LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE`) in a popup that appears after a click over point feature on the map.

I tried the code below, but it is not enough:

```
var popupContent ="";
for (var k in feature.properties) {
    var v = String(feature.properties[k]);
    popupContent += k + '->' + v ;
```

Could someone give some tips on that, please?

Comment: My popup should be like this: NUMERO: 10569 next line MAREGRAFO: COCALZINHO next line FICHA: nulll next line LATITUDE: -4 next line LONGITUDE: -2

Answer (score 1):

Use [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option in `L.GeoJSON` constructor to bind popup to every feature in your GeoJSON. This function will be called for each feature and receive created `L.Marker` and original GeoJSON feature. You can change marker's options, bind popup, etc.

```js
L.geoJson({
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        //use feature.properties to construct popup html
        var popupContent = 'NUMERO: ' + feature.properties.NUMERO;
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lshjdxq/1/

In addition to iterating over the `feature.properties` you also want to display the `feature.geometry.coordinates` (for `Point` features, at least). See the `onEachFeature` method below for details on how to do this.

Also remember: geoJSON uses a grid-based coordinate system, and the coordinates are an array of `[x,y]` which means that the order is `[Longitude, Latidude]`. This is confusing at first but makes sense if you consider that Latitude is the `y` axis and Longitude is the `x` axis. (Many people, in the US at least, are used to saying "latitude and longitude", hence the confusion, which I am pointing out because in your example you said you want to see "LATITUDE: -4 next line LONGITUDE: -2" which is not correct given the coordinates in your example.)

```
// geoJSON data
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "crs": {
        "type": "name",
            "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
        "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            "NUMERO": "10569",
                "MAREGRAFO": "COCALZINHO",
                "FICHA": null
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-117, 45]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            "NUMERO": "50240",
                "MAREGRAFO": "PONTA DE PARANAPUA",
                "FICHA": null
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-118, 44]
        }
    }]
};

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map');

// Set up the OSM layer
var osmTiles = L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
var baseLayer = {
    "Open Street Map": osmTiles
};
var featureLayer = new L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = [];
        // render properties
        for (var key in feature.properties) {
            popupContent.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
        }
        // render coordinates
        if(feature.geometry.type === "Point")
        {
            popupContent.push("Latitude: " + feature.geometry.coordinates[1]);
            popupContent.push("Longitude: " + feature.geometry.coordinates[0]);
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent.join("<br/>"));
    }}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds()).zoomOut(2);
var overlay = {
    "Features": featureLayer
}
var layerControl = new L.control.layers(baseLayer, overlay, {
    collapsed: false
});
map.addControl(layerControl);
```